# Regex to remove values from url

Tags: regex

I have a url

"http://10.160.7.62/b2btoolsce/(S(ivww2d43bvkthvczfpsjdpxe))/UI/PdfViewer.aspx?"

i want to have a regex to remove the contents available in ()
ie (S(ivww2d43bvkthvczfpsjdpxe))

Any ideas?

Comment: What about `http://example.com/(a)/hello(b)/UI`? Most posted solutions will remove `(a)/hello(b)`. What language are you using? Also, are the parentheses properly balanced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use .Net, this is how you remove the parentheses and one of the slashes in C#:

```
 newUrl = Regex.Replace(oldUrl, @"\(.*?\)/", "");
```

This will transform...

```
"http://10.160.7.62/b2btoolsce/(S(ivww2d43bvkthvczfpsjdpxe))/UI/PdfViewer.aspx?"
```

...into...

```
"http://10.160.7.62/b2btoolsce/UI/PdfViewer.aspx?"
```

If you want to replace the parentheses with something, e.g. *edda*, then you write:

```
 newUrl = Regex.Replace(oldUrl, @"\(.*?\)/", "edda/");
```

It will transform...

```
"http://10.160.7.62/b2btoolsce/(S(ivww2d43bvkthvczfpsjdpxe))/UI/PdfViewer.aspx?"
```

...into...

```
"http://10.160.7.62/b2btoolsce/edda/UI/PdfViewer.aspx?"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the possibility of capturing unbalanced parenthesis inside,

```
/\(.*\)/
```

`.*` will try to go as long as possible, so it will capture from the first `(` upto the last `)` in your url. Then, you cam replace this with an empty string to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
b2btoolsce/(?<matchToRemove>\(.*?\))/UI
```

The .*? makes this not greedy.

Answer (score 0):

`/\((.*)\)/`

this is the regular expression you need.